# fMRI ROI analysis: independence

Tags: fmri, spm

In a 2x2 factorial, is it appropriate to look at an interaction at the second-level, group analysis (e.g., using SPM) and define this as an ROI to restrict follow-up main effect contrasts? Or is this an example of a circular, non-independent analysis?